# Rails asset pipeline: How to prevent caching of a specific asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, asset-pipeline

As stated in the title I want to prevent caching of a specific asset, namely a javascript file `something.js.erb`. The situation is like as follows:

Content of `something.js.erb`:

```
...
var something = <%= SomethingHelper.get_something.to_json %>;
...
```

It binds the value from `SomethingHelper` successfully but only once and unless the javascript file is edited by hand the value of `var something` is never assigned again.

This might be somehow expected but clearly doesn't meet my needs. Output of `SomethingHelper.get_something` changes according to call time. So I need to see up-to-date data in my compiled `something.js` file.

My exact need:

- I don't want to disable asset pipeline caching as a whole
- I only want `something.js.erb` to be rendered every time it is requested.

is this even possible?

Environment info:

- Rails 4
- Development mode
- Rails' own server but will be on nginx on prod

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 2 options:

*1)Use inline js to set variable:*

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.something = '<%= j SomethingHelper.get_something.to_json %>';
<% end %>
```

*2)Store the variable in your html and call it from your js:*

```
#html

<body data-something="<%= j SomethingHelper.get_something.to_json %>">
</body>

#js

$("body").data("something");
```

Comment: *Use inline js to set variable*: I was trying to avoid exactly this style in the first place. *Store the variable in your html and call it from your js* this is even uglier than the first one, I think :(

Answer (score 0):

You're marrying front-end business logic with data. This is inadvisable, and one of the reasons I don't use or recommend using ERB + JS for most scenarios (especially triggering behavior on response like Rails tutorials and guides are keen on doing). You are better off either…

1. Firing a request off to fetch the data from your JavaScript.
2. Provided the variable is going to be used on every page (or close to it) and is relatively brief, non-binary data, you can embed a `meta` tag in your layout with the relevant information.

For example:

```
# /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= tag :meta, name: 'something', content: @something %>

# /app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$('meta[name="something"]').attr('content');
```

Comment: 1- how *front-end business logic* is supposed to go on without data? Logically there is no difference between fetching the data via AJAX once the HTML gets loaded and binding the data into js in compile time. At the end in both the data is available to js context when needed.

2- the data is huge, this is the main reason that I am trying to avoid an initial AJAX on dom ready.

Comment: 1) I didn't say logic operates without data, and you don't need to go from one extreme to the other. The difference is pretty significant: separation of concerns, client-side performance, not subverting your architecture, etc. 2) Especially if this is a substantial amount of data you should load it asynchronously (cough, AJAX) as not to keep the main thread from responding while you do so. This allows the client to cache the JS as well as the data if you setup proper HTTP caching in your application, versus neither. You can also avoid running minification on every request to your JS.

Comment: In other words, there's a well established pattern to do what you want and it fits in nicely with your architecture, but you're instead running into a wall because you are insisting on a non-standard design that doesn't offer any benefits (aside from, arguably, slightly less code).

Comment: firstly, thanks for the comments. ok, maybe I couldn't make my point clear. The data is considerably big and the page needs it to be rendered so I don't want the client to waste time waiting for an AJAX response. Moreover the AJAX would be an (unnecessary) extra call which would keep servers busy. So since this is avoidable I am trying to avoid it. Then you would ask 'why rendering the page with js, render it with erb' and it is another 'architectural' requirement originating from the application's nature.

Comment: I really needed this usage and end up putting data between `<scripts>` tags in html. I guess this is uglier and the data needs to be cleared from global scope once used in closures and so on... I would really want to be able to bind json from Rails into javascript files directly and dynamically.

Comment: In my experience the overhead of an AJAX request is minimal, especially compared to loading the data within a blocking call, and I'm relatively confident you'll find the minification and asset fingerprinting adds a non-trivial amount of delay to rendering of your JS. D3.js is built to handle great amounts of data coming in from AJAX requests and rendering it to the DOM (usually in pretty complex ways). I suggest you take a few hours to grok how and why they do this. And again, I point you to caching to resolve most of your performance concerns.